# Edit value with memory pointer using an injected dll

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, dll, code-injection

So I'm playing around with DLL Injection and trying to change the value of my ammo in a small game. I have injected the DLL and it is successful however I am having problems trying to edit memory values.

```
DWORD* address = (DWORD*)((*(DWORD*)(0x00400000 + 0x50F4F4)) + 0x150);  
*(int*)address = value;
```

Whenever I inject the DLL and this piece of code runs it crashes with an Access Violation error, I even tried using VirtualProtect to unprotect the memory and it still crashed. Fairly new to this so any advice is appreciated, thanks

Comment: Most OS's these days use Address Space Layout Randomization (ASLR), where the addresses of things change from in between one run to the next. Check the address of the ammo value across multiple runs.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo I know the addresses are correct as when using them with WriteProcessMemory in a separate executable they work fine just when doing it like this with an injected Dll they throw the Access Violation.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong offset:
`DWORD* address = (DWORD*)((*(DWORD*)(0x00400000 + 0x50F4F4)) + 0x150);`

0x50F4F4 is the absolute virtual address of the local player object in assault cube.  The relative offset is 0x10F4F4.  You should either add 0x10F4F4 to 0x00400000 or just use 0x50F4F4 directly.

Correct code:

```
int* address = (int*)((*(DWORD*)(0x50F4F4)) + 0x150);
*address = 1337;
```

This game does not use ASLR so this is fine.